# Converting 24 format to 12 format with updateDisplay()

Tags: java, time, time-format

I was asked to only used the updateDisplay() method to change the format for the hour in this clockDisplay, eveythings works perfectly the hour can get to 12:59PM and use the method timeTick() it gets to 1:00PM but after using timeTick() again it goes to 1:01AM again. How can i fix this problem?

```
public class ClockDisplay
{
    private NumberDisplay hours;
    private NumberDisplay minutes;
    private String displayString;   

    public ClockDisplay()
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public ClockDisplay(int hour, int minute)
    {
        hours = new NumberDisplay(24);
        minutes = new NumberDisplay(60);
        setTime(hour, minute);
    }

    public void timeTick()
    {
        minutes.increment();
        if(minutes.getValue() == 0) {  // it just rolled over!
            hours.increment();
        }
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public void setTime(int hour, int minute)
    {
        hours.setValue(hour);
        minutes.setValue(minute);
        updateDisplay();
    }

    public String getTime()
    {
        return displayString;
    }    

    private void updateDisplay()
    {
        int h = hours.getValue()%12;
        String format = (hours.getValue()/12 == 0 ? "AM":"PM");
        if(h == 0)
        {
            h = 12;
        }
        else if(hours.getValue() > 12)
        {
            hours.setValue(hours.getValue() - 12);
        }
        displayString = hours.getDisplayValue() + ":" + 
        minutes.getDisplayValue() + format;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the date/time formatting methods that are built into the Java run-time library?

Comment: Please post the full package and object name and/or whether you are using any particular date library. Also, a sample runnable program to reproduce the error is reccommended.

Comment: Because the teacher told me only to use this method to change the format.

Comment: You want to print 'AM' only when hours is less than 12, otherwise print 'PM'. Your line setting `format` does not do this.

Comment: So i need to change format in another way.

Comment: If this is a programming execise (for school or self study), it’s a nice one. For production code you would rather use `LocalTime` and a `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: **Warning**: You are calling an overridable method (`setTime`) in your `ClockDisplay(int, int)` constructor. That can cause trouble when someone extends this class.

Answer (score 0):

**What’s wrong?** When the time reaches 1 PM, your `updateDisplay` method sets the value of the hours display back to 1. Now your clock display object is back in the state it had at 1 AM, that is, you have no way of distinguishing those two times.

**How to fix?** I suggest you introduce an instance variable (field) to hold the information whether we are in the AM or PM period of the day. You may use a Boolean variable or introduce an `enum` with two constants like `AM` and `PM`. Then you need to set this variable in the `timeTick` method and also in your `setTime` method. Then it will be fairly straightforward to use this variable to decide whether to display the string `AM` or `PM` in your `updateDisplay` method.

If you are asked to do this **without adding a new field**: then you need to let the hours in the `hours` display run to 23 so you keep track of whether you are in the AM or PM time of day. So in `updateDisplay` don’t set the hours value. Only in the display string generated put 12 instead of 0 and 1 through 11 instead of 13 through 23.

**For production code:** In real life one wouldn’t use a design like yours and would rely heavily on standard library classes for handling time. One would have a clearer separation between model (the current time) and presentation (the string printed). So the current time would be held in a `LocalTime`:

```
    private LocalTime time;
```

Ticking the time 1 minut forward:

```
        time = time.plusMinutes(1);
```

For displaying the time you would use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
    private static final DateTimeFormatter TIME_FORMATTER
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.SHORT);
```

With this the display string is created this way:

```
        displayString = time.format(TIME_FORMATTER);
```

The code is not tested, so forgive if there is a typo.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it never occurred to me to have an instance to hold the info. sorry i cant give you a thumb up